# Fortrabbit deployment error on push

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, fortrabbit

I'm trying to deploy an app on fortrabbit but I'm getting some problems, the latest one is this, even If I comment that line it just goes straing to the next provider, I don't know what to do anymore. Everything works perfectly locally.

```
> php artisan optimize
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Class 'Netshell\Paypal\PaypalServiceProvider' not found
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

---

```
A B O R T E D
!! Failure in build execution: Failure in composer execution
To deploy.eu2.frbit.com:DOMAIN.git
a31bb76..f8a1628 master -> master
error: failed to push some refs to 'MYDOMAINHERE'
```

Comment: Can you post the full output ?

Comment: Can you show your composer.json

Comment: Stack says its too long to post